# Java - Factorial

Tags: java

I am printing the factorial of the first 10 numbers, so it is 0 - 9. The below code works for me. But I am unable to make the loop such that the factorial of 0 is within the loop too. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

```
public class fact {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("\n\n(f) Loop to print first 10 factorial numbers");

        System.out.println("\nFactorial of 0 is 1");

        int fact = 1; 
        int index = 1; 
        while (index < 10) 

        { 
            fact*=index; 
            System.out.println("Factorial of " + index + " is " + fact); 
            index++; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding an `if` condition in your `while` loop for index 0

```
    int fact = 1; 
    int index = 0; 
    while (index < 10) 

    { 

        if(index == 0)
          System.out.println("\nFactorial of 0 is 1");
        else {
           fact*=index; 
           System.out.println("Factorial of " + index + " is " + fact); 
       }
       index++; 
    }
```

Comment: Yeaaaah, infinite loop ! Move the `index++` outside the if/else statement

Answer (score 1):

The factorial of 0 is a special case, so you are better off printing it outside the loop, just as you are doing now.

Answer (score 1):

For big  n  numbers find factorial and its digit count .

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class N_Faktorial {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        { 
           int u=1,A[]=new int[9999999];
           Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("n=");
          int n=scan.nextInt();
          A[1]=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) 
        {
           for(int j=1;j<=n;j++) {
                A[j]*=i;
            }           
           for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
           {
             if(A[j]>9)
              {
              A[j+1]+=A[j]/10;
              A[j]%=10;       
              }
             if(A[u+1]!=0) {
                   u++;
               } 
           }

       }
        System.out.print(n+"! digit count:"+u+"\\n Result: \\n");
         for(int i=u;i>=1;i--)
         {
             System.out.print(A[i]);
         }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
    int fact = 1; 
    int index = 0; 
    while (index < 10) 

    { 
        fact=(index==0)?1:fact*(index);
        System.out.println("Factorial of " + index + " is " + fact); 
        index++; 
    }
```

Comment: Why not simply `fact=(index==0)?1:fact*(index);`?

Answer (score 0):

```
factorialList(10);

public static int factorialList(int indexMax) {
    int fact = 1;
    if (indexMax > 0) fact = indexMax * factorialList(indexMax - 1);
    System.out.println("Factorial of " + indexMax + " is " + fact);
    return fact;
}
```

Fn calls are less effective than loops but I bet it would be optimized to ~ the same on task of this size.

Comment: ty, fixed. I keep forgetting those after couple of months with Scala ^^ I guess I could have squeezed helper with accumulator in there to make it tail recursive ... no point in java, just for looks.